# Kendo UI ListviewControl

Tags: kendo-ui

is it possible to activate virtual scrolling ListView control instead pageing as in the grid? I try this but don't work

```
        var options = {
                autoBind : true,
                dataSource : kendoDataSource,
                selectable: true,
                template: function (record) {
                    var tmpl = kendo.template(m_DataSet.getReadTemplate(record));
                    return tmpl(record);
                },
                filterable: {
                    field : "ID"
                },
                scrollable: {
                    virtual: true
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                edit : function (e) {
                    $(e.item).find("input:eq(0)").focus();
                }
            };
```

$(m_ListViewItemTag).kendoListView(options);

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo UI ListView does **not** support virtual scrolling.